# How can I increase the font size of names

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I currently have the problem that the names above the heads of NPCs and players scale very poorly. This makes the names impossible to read when fully zoomed out. ([**Screenshot for reference**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekmrx.jpg))

Note that I'm talking about the **name text** not about nameplates.

My guess is that this issue is caused by the addon(collection) ElvUI since I can change the font style there, however I can't find anything that changes the font size or scaling.

How can I fix the scaling of the names so they remain readable even when fully zoomed out?

Comment: I'm unable to get a ss since I'm at work, but you should be able to adjust font sizes from the general settings in ElvUI. I also use ElvUI and I have all my fonts customized.

Comment: @nukeforum In the general settings there is an option for "general font size", however this ignores the name text for some reason...

Comment: Hmm, it's been awhile since I've gone digging around in the settings. I'll try to update this when I get home if there still hasn't been any activity here.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your options are limited here, because Blizzard decided to make those settings non-accessible.

This issue is not caused by ElvUI or any other addon. Blizzard changed the way texts are rendered and messed up those fonts, because they never planned to have them scaled up that far (remember when they talked about limiting the camera distance). Also according to some reading it is not possible for any addon to access the size, outline, etc. of the these system names.

What I've figured to be helpful so far:

- Change your Anti-Alias settings. Better settings make them better to read. This will likely cost you some FPS, though. Turning AA off helps as well, but that makes the game look like it's from 1990.
- Turn on nameplates and enjoy your self-designed layout using your ElvUI options.
- Use ElvUI or any other addon that does that and change the font of the names. Using an easy-to-read font can be helpful as well. ElvUI can not change the size of it without nameplates enabled.
  For ElvUI:

  1. type /ec
  2. Under General click on Media
  3. Change the *Name Font* to something easy-to-read
  4. Restart the game. Reloading does nothing, because you can change it only once per session and ElvUI already did that. (You can use the *Default Font* option to look for your desired font in the first place and then try it out when you found one. This saves a lot of restarts.
  5. If you run out of fonts use an  addon like *SharedMediaAdditionalFonts* to install a bunch of additional fonts.